# Delete mysql unspecifying column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to make a request like this one:

```
DELETE * FROM '" . $my_table . "' 
WHERE 1 AND '--my first column--' = '" . $my_id . "';
```

The main idea is to delete, no matter what the first column's name of my table is, every rows is like my value, unspecifying the column name.

In CSS I would write:

```
WHERE column:nth-child(0) = $my_id
```

Do you know if this is possible? And how it works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, stuffing the tags list full of the same words that you put in your question title isn't going to make it easier for others to find your question.

Comment: I really hope you're [properly escaping your SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/) and not just putting in unqualified arbitrary user-supplied content like `$my_id`.

Answer (score 2):

First run:

```
DESC `table`;
```

Then use the column name retrieved in the DESC in your DELETE.

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `column-name` = value;
```